# Deflection of Cantilever Beam with Midpoint Spring, Integration and Superposition Methods

Tags: beam, strength, springs, deflection

How can I get the deflection required below using 1) the Integration and 2) Superposition methods (two ways)?

The beam $AB$ is supported by a spring $CD$, which is fixed at $C$ with constant $k$, and is fixed at $B$ to a rigid wall. If $W$ and $M_0$ act on A and are given as follows, find the deflection at $A$ and midpoint $C$. $EI$ are constant and ignore bar and spring weights.

$$W = \frac{12EI\delta}{L^3}$$
$$M_0 = \frac{6EI\delta}{L^2}$$

[image]

[image]

The questions are

1. Can I use these two coordinates $(x_1, x_2)$ for finding the deflection at A and C? If not why?
2. How the reaction force due to the spring will take its part in the problem? Through the reaction force at $(V_B)$?

Comment: Have you tried solving the problem, or just asking for free help?

Comment: Actually, this is a two part problem. I solved the first, which is the input for this one, had to find M_0 and W in another setup. Then, I tried to solve this one by the Integration method using two coordinates (x1 and x2), both starting from A. However, it is getting too difficult to solve the problem, and at the exam, I just have 15 min to solve something like this. With the Superposition, I have no ideia what kind of assumption should I made and what are the compatibility/continuity equations. So, with this last method I could not even start solving.

Comment: Since there is not much we can say about the spring, you may want to attack this problem by releasing the rotation restrain of the fixed end, solving for reactions, and noting the angle of rotation of point "B". Then with all load removed, apply a moment at point "B" to bring it back to zero rotation. Superimpose the results from each step to form the final results.

Comment: Could you please give a starting solution for the problem? I trying using Integration method, but things are just going wrong. I also tried using Macaulay's method without luck.

Comment: I've to admit that this problem is tricky due to the spring support. I think you have to figure out the capacity of the spring by imagining that, by itself,  the cantilever beam representing a spring with Kb = 3EI/L^3, and combined, the total deflection = P/(Ks+Kb), from here, you can proportion out the share of the spring when loaded by the real load, which is one of the boundary conditions. I suggest using the consistent displacement method to solve this problem because we don't know the characteristics of rotation at point "C", which is required when using double integration method.

Comment: Just noticed, where is the deflection "delta" (in EQ for W & Mo) located on the system, at the free end? It is weird to indicate forces this way.